# Sitecore Experience Editor Ribbon not loading?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9, experience-editor

I have a sitecore 9 project. When i load the Experience Editor the Ribbon iframe has a Server Error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: SpriteStorageNode
```

Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking [at the code](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/Debugging-framework-internals-without-source-code), the likely culprit code lives in `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Web.Sprites.SpriteDefinitionManager` constructor.

The `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Constants.ItemIDs.SpritesRoot` item seems missing in your solution.

Item is expected to live under `/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Sprites` in `core` database.

You could attach clean/blank core db to the solution to test the assumption.